# Ember.js Why is an itemcontroller needed with Ember.Select option value

Tags: ember.js

After a lot of fiddling I realized that I needed to specify an itemcontroller in my ArrayController 'Markets'. It was needed to get access to a computed property in the ObjectController 'Market'.

My question is, why is this needed? Because the ObjectController is in my perception linked to the corresponding ArrayController?

**I setup the controller in the application Route**

```
// routes/application.js
model: function() {
    this.controllerFor('markets').set('model', this.store.find('market'));
}
```

**The Ember.Select in a .hbs file**

```
// views/article/someViewForARoute.hbs
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="controller.controllers.markets" 
optionLabelPath="content.nameWithTime" optionValuePath="content.id"}}
```

**The Market ObjectController**

```
// controllers/market.js
nameWithTime: function() {
    return this.get('name') + ' (' + this.get('time') + ')';
}.property('name', 'time')
```

**The Markets ArrayController**

```
// controllers/markets.js
itemController: 'market' // Why needed?
```

This question is only asking the reason why specifying itemcontroller this way is needed in Ember.js. Thanks for any clearification!

Comment: can you post your code in jsbin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the ObjectController is in my perception linked to the corresponding ArrayController?

In no way this is done, and such a behaviour isn't documented anywhere.

No ArrayController will have an itemController linked by default, The default value for itemController of an ArrayController is `null` Refer [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_itemController).

If you don't want the computed property inside the `marketController`, better you can have that property in the `marketModel`.

Comment: Aha, but they are 'linked' when using the correct master/child template setup. But that is done by the router. It is clear now, thanks!